# How to modify Info.plist file of iOS application after the ipa file is created and signed for multi-environment release pipeline

Tags: ios, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment, ipa, info.plist

We have an application that targets 2 different backend environments, let's say Staging and Production. Each has its own set of urls and configurations. Currently, we rebuild the whole app every time we won't to make a release to a specific environment with different bundle id and configuration set. However, that's not ideal. Ideally, we would like to have a build and release pipeline. Build will happen only once, then the release pipeline will have a step to make a release to Staging and another step to Production.

Solving the resigning of the application with new bundle id and provisioning profile is easy, we use `fastlane run  resign` command. However, I have no idea how can I modify the contents of the bundle in the same command not to break the signing. What I imagine is having a property in `Info.plist`, let's say `Environment`. In the code I'd read that value and if the value is say "Staging", it'd use the staging url configurations, otherwise production.

Even better and even more flexible approach would be having a separate `.plist` file for configurations, which would store all of the relevant configs, and then we would substitute it with a different file during the release process. This has the benefit of having yet another environment support without changing the code. In the first approach every time environment properties are changed, or new environment is created we would need to change the code by adding yet another `if` statement.

Anyway, as for now we at least need to be able to specify the environment. If the latter file substitution is not possible, then I hope Info.plist modification might work.

And BTW, we use the file substitution approach on Android, and it works like a breeze. We use `apktool` tool to unpack the apk, substitute the configuration file and then repack and resign it.

Thanks for the replies.

Comment: Did you find an answer to this? I also need the exact same functionality. Currently I'm using fastlane gym to build & archive my app but I'm wondering if I should just use the xcode tools and build without archiving, later, before TestFlight upload (we use Octopus for testflight deployments), change the info.plist as needed, archive & sign before uploading... That's my thinking

Comment: Sorry @nonstopcoding I just saw your comment. I do believe that fastlane is the way to go, but it was too time consuming to figure this out. We have gone with a way of rebuilding the app and having 2 builds per environment. But I am definitely going to revisit this and put a proper CI/CD pipeline with 1-build-multiple-releases ideology at some point